# How to keep the session variable even after page refresh automatically

Tags: php, mysql, session

My sensor device is sending some new data to DB every 10 seconds. I am trying to display these data when the user presses a button (Start_Now) to show data from now onwards. I am saving the button press time in a session variable and using that time data in the sql query to extract data. But my problem is as I have new data every 10 seconds, I should refresh the page automatically every 10 seconds. But it will change the session variable to new refresh time. How to avoid it?

```
// a button to Start_Now- Not showed
//session already started... include('session.php');
//page refreshes every 10 seconds

$sqlTime =NULL;     // a time variable to include in sql query
//button press time will be saved in a session variable
if (isset($_GET['Start_Now'])){
    $timeNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
    $_SESSION['timeNowSession'] = $timeNow
}

include ("connect.php");
$conn= mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db );
if ($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

$sqlTime =$_SESSION['timeNowSession'];
if ($sqlTime !=NULL)
   {
     $sql = "SELECT Data FROM MyDB AND Date > '$sqlTime' ORDER BY Date DESC;

   }

//Rest of the code to execute query and display data
```

Comment: Do you start your session with `session_start();` ?

Comment: ya sure. even though I haven't shown. I have a login page.

Comment: Great, but you need to start that session on every page. Otherwise, you will lose your session variables

Comment: I have added `include('session.php');` that contians session validation.

Comment: here the problem is, page refreshing has the same effect as when the user pressed the Start_Now button. So it resets the session variable to last page refresh time!

Comment: if your url contains the ?Start_Now parameter, the date will be reset every time, so you should add a check if the session variable exists

Comment: @Wietse yes my url contains it. So you mean some `if` condition checks to avoid resetting it during refreshing?

Comment: Yes, you should check for both the url-parameter, and wheter the session variable already exists (to make sure it doesn't reset), something like: `if (isset($_GET['Start_Now']) && !isset($_SESSION['timeNowSession'])) {`

Answer (score -1):

```
//button press time will be saved in a session variable
if (isset($_GET['Start_Now'])){
```

I think you already have the code written
maybe you can use isset with $_SESSION also.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
  session_start();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

To use session variables you must have start session on every page.So just put this code as below at header of your page.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
   session_start();
```

Comment: Please read the comments, I already asked the 'asker' if he starts the session. Don't assume things, but check, check and double check

Comment: I did it already. My problem is refreshing the page has the same effect as the user pressed Start_Now button. so it resets the session variable to new time